# Disable Spring Configuration if one of several profiles is present

Tags: spring, configuration, profile

As expected, this Configuration will not load if `moduleTest`is an active profile:

```
@Profile({"!moduleTest"})
@Configuration
public class UserConfig {
}
```

However, this configuration *will* load:

```
@Profile({"!moduleTest", "!featureTest"})
@Configuration
public class UserConfig {
}
```

Is there a way to have a Configuration that will *not* load if `moduleTest` *or* `featureTest` is active?

Comment: `@Configuration` is a spring bean, so try to use `@Conditional`. You will need spring boot for that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a simple (undocumented, but I think officially supported) way of doing this:

```
@Profile("!moduleTest & !featureTest")
```

By default Spring is using logical OR, this forces it to logical AND.

Comment: Nice find! I see that [it's documented in the javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html): *A profile expression allows for more complicated profile logic to be expressed, for example "p1 & p2"*.  More info in the [Profiles.of](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Profiles.html#of-java.lang.String...-) javadoc.

Comment: Ah you're right, it is mentioned, easy to overlook though. They should add an example for this scenario.

Comment: Just to add some context: That change was introduced in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/1f3b4f1863cdc27f28723659872e5e303ed7e12a, almost two years after this question was asked :)

Answer (score 15):

Try using a condition:

```
@Configuration
@Conditional(LoadIfNotModuleNorTestProfileCondition.class)
public class UserConfig {
}
```

**LoadIfNotModuleNorTestProfileCondition class:**

```
public class LoadIfNotModuleNorTestProfileCondition implements ConfigurationCondition{

    @Override
    public ConfigurationPhase getConfigurationPhase() {
        return ConfigurationPhase.PARSE_CONFIGURATION;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        String[] activeProfiles = context.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles();
        for (String profile : activeProfiles) {
            if(profile.equalsIgnoreCase("moduleTest") || profile.equalsIgnoreCase("featureTest")){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```